# For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $rx\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'd like to prove (or disprove) the statement in the title. I know that if $x$ is rational the result is trivially true. If $x$ is irrational, then $r$ must be irrational as well since the product of a rational and an irrational is always irrational.

My doubt is whether for any irrational there exists an irrational such that the product is rational. I don't even know if I should prove it or disprove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But of course, trivialy take $r=1/x$.

Comment: Omg I don't know how I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb Q$, take $r=\frac1x$. Then $xr=1\in\mathbb  Q$.

Comment: You also need to include an exception for $x=0$.

Comment: No, he doesn't, since $0\notin \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I mean, he also needs to take care of $x=0$ for his answer to be complete.